# Handling large dataset in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, php-7

I have product records above 60,000 ,
When I fire a query with PHPMyAdmin -> SQL it gets result instantly but when I use same with codeigniter pagination it will lag,

take too much time to load page

is their any way to handle this
[image: sh]

Comment: URL for above open in new tab https://www.a2zmarketresearch.com/report?rootCatId=1&subCatId=0

Comment: Have your search columns are indexed properly in database?

Comment: what kind of indexed , insertion is done in correct way , is their anything need to change there @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA

Comment: how long your query is taking in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: just few seconds where as in coding it will take few minutes, which may be decrease the page load speed @SeniorTeamLeadPHP

Comment: can you tell me exact numbers right after the decimal?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 24 (7341 total, Query took 0.0072 seconds.) @SeniorTeamLeadPHP

Comment: now your query please, I am quite close to your issue.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `products` JOIN `main_category` ON `products`.`main_category_id` = `main_category`.`main_category_id` WHERE `products`.`main_category_id` = 1 LIMIT 5 @SeniorTeamLeadPHP

Comment: first of all, remove asterisk ( * ) and define required columns only and also check if you properly indexed the main_category_id in both tables and also check the physical relationship between these two tables for main_category_id column. There should be a proper primary and foreign key relationship between columns

Answer (score 2):

It solves with when counting the records 
`num_rows()` takes **20 seconds**
where as 
`$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count')` with get()->row() 
it will take just **0.63 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

Generally the speed of your queries are based on indexes and references. I would suggest that you check that first.

You can use the 'Explain' statement to get a better idea as to how to optimize your query. Here is more information directly from the MySQL site.

[Using Explain Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html)

I would also highly recommend turning on 'profiler' for CI to determine where the bottle neck actually is.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Thirdly if I am not able to get any additional information back based on your profiler I would alternately recommend you using jQuery datatables in conjunction with CI, its server side processing can handle millions of rows within a short time. It will only load the page that is currently active to make things a lot more simpler and easier on the users end.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: Yes I enable it could please look into this @Enoch

Comment: URL for above open in new tab https://www.a2zmarketresearch.com/report?rootCatId=1&subCatId=0 @Enoch